# Is there an action hook that fires just before a template is loaded?

Tags: templates, hooks, actions

I'm looking for an action hook that occurs just before a template is parsed but AFTER the query has run and the variables are present.

So if it's going to run index.php, just before it starts reading code from line 1 of index.php, some hook would be super useful.

Anyone know one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in the Codex, the first action listed after the `wp` action that sets up the WP object is [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/), which is indeed fired after all queried data is available, and before a template is selected. You can use the WordPress conditionals to determine if your intended template file will be loaded.

There is also [the `template_include` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) which is executed after a template has been selected but before it is loaded, and gets passed the selected template file as an argument. But you should note that as this is a [filter hook](https://wordpress.org/support/article/glossary/#filter), it's intended purpose is to replace a selected template rather than adding or removing functionality.

Alternately, if you are using your own theme, you could call `do_action( 'my_custom_action' );` at the top of your template file and simply add hooks to the action to execute custom functionality.

Comment: +1. For sake of completeness, between `'template_redirect'` and `'template_include'` there is another filter hook fired, that is variable depending on the query type. Is the [`"{$type}_template"`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b75c79500b5a668c147114d416045605924d9aa8/wp-includes/template.php#L41) e.g. in case of `index.php` it will be `'index_termplate'`.